# How to check Physical Memory (RAM) DDR type by Excel/Access vba?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to get physical memory DDR information like `DDR3 or DDR4` by Excel/Access VBA. My below sub give me details about physical memory but do not give any DDR information.

```
Sub RAMDetails()
Dim oWMISrvEx As Object
Dim oWMIObjSet As Object
Dim oWMIObjEx As Object
Dim oWMIProp As Object
Dim sWQL As String
Dim n

Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

sWQL = "Select * From Win32_PhysicalMemory"


Set oWMISrvEx = GetObject("winmgmts:root/CIMV2")
Set oWMIObjSet = oWMISrvEx.ExecQuery(sWQL)
intRow = 2
strRow = Str(intRow)

sht.Range("A1").Value = "Name"
sht.Cells(1, 1).Font.Bold = True

sht.Range("B1").Value = "Value"
sht.Cells(1, 2).Font.Bold = True

For Each oWMIObjEx In oWMIObjSet
    For Each oWMIProp In oWMIObjEx.Properties_
        If Not IsNull(oWMIProp.Value) Then

            If IsArray(oWMIProp.Value) Then
                For n = LBound(oWMIProp.Value) To UBound(oWMIProp.Value)
                    Debug.Print oWMIProp.Name & "(" & n & ")", oWMIProp.Value(n)
                      sht.Range("A" & Trim(strRow)).Value = oWMIProp.Name
                        sht.Range("B" & Trim(strRow)).Value = oWMIProp.Value(n)
                        sht.Range("B" & Trim(strRow)).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
                       intRow = intRow + 1
                    strRow = Str(intRow)
                Next

                Else
                    sht.Range("A" & Trim(strRow)).Value = oWMIProp.Name
                       sht.Range("B" & Trim(strRow)).Value = oWMIProp.Value
                        sht.Range("B" & Trim(strRow)).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
                       intRow = intRow + 1
                    strRow = Str(intRow)
            End If

        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: IMO it does, look at the memory type and decide based on this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/win32-physicalmemory). If memory type is equal 24 then you've got DDR3 and if it's 21 or 22 than you've got DDR2. DDR4 is not documented or not supported I guess but I do not know for sure.

Comment: @Storax Let me check and know.